# iPhone/iPad Safari Javascript performance

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, safari

Do anyone know how to improve response time of panning (using one finger gesture) handled using JavaScript in Safari on iPad/iPhone

Comment: Use Dashcode and only Dashcode? Does that help with movement?

Comment: @thyrgle, No i must have to use safari as its the requirement. 

@Chris...very funny chris, that won't help solve the problem

Comment: Dashcode uses Safari. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specific example of a web-site that is bad?

The user manual for the iPhone that is included with the standard bookmarks in Mobile Safari is implemented in Javascript and is almost as fluent as native code.

See:
[what is the pastrykit framework - stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143589/what-is-the-pastrykit-framework/)

Comment: @Jonathan...yes its so smooth, let me look at that and ur link, then i'll get back to you if I solve this problem.